# No visible points for plot in for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, plot, matlab-figure

I'm struggling with a plot I want to make using a for-loop.

I know it works when I add it after the loop (just a simple plot). But I want to try it in this other way.

```matlab
fib = ones(1:10);
for k=3:10
    hold on
    fib(k) = fib(k-1) + fib(k-2);
    plot(k,fib(k))
end
hold off
```

The output is a plot, but there are no points visible.

Comment: You need to specify a marker.

Comment: You might want to initialize `fib` as `fib = ones(10, 1)`. Using your statement, you get some 10-dimensional monster.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify a marker. The documentation says:

> If one of `X` or `Y` is a scalar and the other is either a scalar or a vector, then the plot function plots discrete points. However, to see the points you must specify a marker symbol, for example, `plot(X,Y,'o')`

So it will be:

```
plot(k,fib(k),'o');
```

---

Also note that you're creating a 10-dimensional array with `fib = ones(1:10);`. You most probably meant to write a comma instead of colon in between 1 and 10 to create a row vector. i.e.

```
fib = ones(1,10);
```

or a column vector as [HansHirse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11089932/hanshirse) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56166314/how-to-fix-this-using-a-for-loop-to-plot-as-an-exercise#comment98959550_56166314):

```
fib = ones(10,1);
```